# Passing values from one database to another database and back again in Talend ETL

Tags: etl, talend

I'm not sure I understand the limits of Talend ETL: specifically, what can be done graphically and what has to be done through code.

Ultimately, I want to store the variable from one database's SELECT query and pipe it into another's SELECT query, and then finally use the results of that query to create an INSERT back into the first database. I guess what I want to do is dynamically modify the (under the covers) SQL statements used by the database components in an ETL job. Here's my specific scenario.

Problem: I obtain a batch of events from a production database and store them in a data warehouse. Each time I run the batch, I need to see what is the ID of the last event obtained by the most recently run batch. I store this ID in my data warehouse. Using that ID, I query the production database to run a batch. I then want to record the start and end ID's of the events from that batch.

Note: These are two physically separate databases, each requiring their own connection.

Here it is in SQL code (and some pseudo code):

**Databases**

```
WarehouseDB

+==============+
| BatchEvents  |
+==============+
| StartingID   |
| EndingID     |
| ...          |
+--------------+

ProductionDB

+=============+
| ProdEvents  |
+=============+
| ProdEventID |
| ...         |
+-------------+
```

**Step 1:**

```
USE WarehouseDB;
SELECT MAX(EndingID) FROM BatchEvents;
```

The resulting value we will call: end_id

**Step 2:**

```
USE ProductionDB;
SELECT MIN(ProdEventID) FROM ProdEvents 
    WHERE ProdEventID IN (
        SELECT TOP 500 ProdEventID FROM ProdEvents WHERE ProdEventID > [end_id]
        );
```

The resulting variable we will call: new_start_id

```
SELECT MAX(ProdEventID) FROM ProdEvents 
    WHERE ProdEventID IN (
        SELECT TOP 500 ProdEventID FROM ProdEvents WHERE ProdEventID > [new_start_id]
        );
```

The resulting value we will call: new_end_id

**Step 3:**

```
USE WarehouseDB;
INSERT INTO BatchEvents (StartingID, EndingID) VALUES ([new_start_id], [new_end_id]);
```

What's the best practice for the problem I outline below? If much of this can be done graphically, using Talend ETL, what are the components I will need; and, if some of it needs to be done in code, where do I draw the line?

Answer (score 1):

You have several different ways to accomplish yyour task. Assuming you're using a OracleRDBMS as example, IMO the best way is to pipe operations this way:

```
tOracleInput---->tOracleRow---->tParseRecordSet---->tOracleOutput
```

let me try to explain:

tOracleInput handles your Step 1 and will carry your value to the outgoing connection (remember to match the name between the DB field/alias and the Talend column name)

tOracleRow with a prepared statement will trig a general query to the RDBMS using parameters coming from the incoming collection

Since tOracleRow returns a ResultSet in raw form only, you need to parse to actual columns using a tParseRecordSet instance

Finally, a simple tORacleOut will carry your trivial insert operation

[here's a tutorial](http://gabrielebaldassarre.com/2014/03/16/using-rdbms-prepared-statements-increase-efficiency-security-talend-queries/) on how to use tOracleRow to fast lookup or pipe prepared sql statements inside a data flow

Comment: My two databases are MySQL and MSSQL Server. So, I'm guessing what I need to do is something more along the lines of:

tMySQLInput --> tMSSQLRow --> tParseRecordSet --> tMySQLOutput 

Yes?